# Working cvlc A/V stream

Tags: alsa, cvlc, raspivid

I am able to get audio or video, but not both (I am relatively unfamiliar with the 5k lines of VLC options).

```
/usr/bin/nohup /opt/vc/bin/raspivid -mm matrix -br 60 -co 10 --nopreview -qp 30 -b 200000 -fps 15 -h 720 -w 1280 -hf -vf -o - -t 0 2>/dev/null | \
/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/cvlc stream:///dev/stdin :input-slave=alsa://hw:1,0 --sout "#transcode{acodec=mp2}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/}" :demux=mp2,h264 2>/dev/null >/dev/null &
```

VLC on the receiving end:

- Shows video but no audio.
- No messages, errors/warnings.
- Codec details shows an audio stream

VLC on the sending end gets flooded with:

```
[b5f00508] core input error: demux doesn't like DEMUX_GET_TIME
```

Please recommend a cvlc working command for audio and video.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is exactly what you need, but if VLC is not a requirement, there is a standard solution with `WebRTC` for [UV4L](http://linux-projects.org). It can live stream both A/V to any browser in RealTime (< 150ms).

Comment: UV4L documentation said webrtc won't work on the first revision rpi. (maybe it's to CPU heavy?)  VLC uses <2% CPU and I would rather learn how to use vlc properly.